# Spring Boot / Docker: Thymeleaf template not found for html mail

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, thymeleaf

I have a problem with finding a thymeleaf template on docker. I'm familiar with the [leading slash problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57221353/thymeleaf-fails-to-resolve-templates-when-running-inside-docker-container) in ordinary controllers. However I'd now like to use thymeleaf to render email bodies.

My code looks like this:

```
@Component
public class HtmlEmailDocumenter implements Documenter {

    @Autowired
    SpringTemplateEngine thymeleafTemplateEngine;

    // more dependencies

    @Override
    public void accept(Documentable documentable){
        Context thymeleafContext = new Context();
        thymeleafContext.setVariable("doc", documentable);

        String template = "mail/default";
        String htmlBody = thymeleafTemplateEngine.process(template, thymeleafContext);

        // send the email...
    }
}
```

The template in question is under `/src/main/resources/templates/mail/default.html`. I have alternatively tried using "mail/default.html" in the source code. Doesn't work either in docker.

Any hints welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something similar in non-Boot Spring application by defining the template engine template and resolver as follows:

```
  @Bean
  public ResourceBundleMessageSource emailMessageSource() {
    final ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("templates/email/mailMessages");
    return messageSource;
  }

  @Bean
  public TemplateEngine emailTemplateEngine() {
    final SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(htmlTemplateResolver());
    templateEngine.setTemplateEngineMessageSource(emailMessageSource());
    return templateEngine;
  }

  private ITemplateResolver htmlTemplateResolver() {
    final ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setOrder(Integer.valueOf(2));
    templateResolver.setPrefix("/templates/email/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
    return templateResolver;
  }
```

I then refer to an email message template using just the name of the template within the /templates/email directory without extension.